# Array not looping correctly - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with 60 values, and when I click the next button, it will cycle through all of the values of my array in ascending order until the number 60, then it starts at number one again.

I also have a previous button, so I can go down values instead of going up. When I hit the previous button on the first array value [0], my app crashes and I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
public String nextFact() {
    i++;
    if(i >= facts.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    return facts[i];
}

public String previousFact() {
    i--;
    if(i < 0) {
        i = facts.length;
    }
    return facts[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think that `i = facts.length;` and `facts[i];` are correct? I mean you obviously know that the length of an array is not a valid index, since you avoid that number in `nextFact`, but in `previousFact` you think otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you change `i` to `facts.length`, because valid array indexes range from `0` through `facts.length - 1`.  Set `i` to `facts.length - 1`.

```
if(i < 0) {
    i = facts.length - 1;
}
```

Your wrapping-around code for greater than or equal to the length should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of size array.length. So the last index will be array.length-1. In your previous function, you assign array.length to i. This is larger index than max index for array and therefore it crashes down. You must be getting am indexoutofbound error too.

You should replace that line with this:

```
i = facts.length - 1;
```